# Add extra fields to fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to create more fields for my calendar ( fullcalendar hooked up to mysql with php ). And I have been reading up on eventRender but I'm not entirely sure of the syntax and where I should put it.

Currently I have the following;

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
  timeslotsPerHour : 4,
  defaultView:'agendaWeek',
  allowCalEventOverlap : true,
  overlapEventsSeparate: true,
  firstDayOfWeek : 1,
  businessHours :{start: 8, end: 18, limitDisplay: true },
  daysToShow : 7,
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        editable: true,
        events: "json-events.php",
  eventRender : function(calEvent, $event) {
       calEvent.distributor  //this is my new field

  },
```

But I its not working and I can't find any working examples to compare it with. 
Thanks

---

Thanks for the feedback I have been able to add my custom fields using the eventRender. So now not just body and description are being passed.

My main issue now is passing the date values to the database as these are not being saved. Does anyone know of any examples where this is being used. I would really really appreciated it.

Comment: Are you definitely getting calEvent.distributor back from the server in the JSON object? Please post "json-events.php" so we can track down the problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can include your own non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify or delete these fields.,this example help you [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

and see [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Answer (score 19):

In version 4 of fullcalendar, to get non-standard field is changed a little bit. Now it accepts just one parameter as Event Object:

```
 events: [
{
  title: 'My Event',
  start: '2010-01-01',
  description: 'This is a cool event'
}
// more events here
],
eventRender: function(info) {
  console.log(info.event.extendedProps.description);
}
```

**Note:** You can access an additional field in this way: **info.event.extendedProps.description**

[Check documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender)

Comment: this also will work: `extendedProps: { 'description': 'This is a cool event' }'` and the usage is `info.event.extendedProps['description']`

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I used eventRender to add some categories to each event. Then I can filter events based on category name

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.attr("categories",event.categoryname)
    }
```

Simply awesome calendar

Comment: I am trying to use the above code but I cannot make it work.When the event is rendered I only get to see title,start,end...nothing else.I am trying to build a calendar based on this tutorial http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/...it is difficult to post code in this comment section.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in chrome dev tools console...categoryname is shown as undefined

Comment: is the extra field going to be "printed" in the timeslot such as title and start/end date?

Comment: Hi Dimitris - I looked at my code, make sure the events you pass to the calendar have the fields you need and then you can access those fields inside the eventrender function. So categoryname was my field name, it is not part of the calendar.

Answer (score -3):

Some attributes here:

```
{
title: 'Birthday Party',
start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
allDay: false,
backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
},
```